# MongoDB aggregation - distance sort inside aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to perform search by text and return results sorted by distance.

The first solution was to perform $geoNear query and than to perform a $match to get needed results. This solution is way problematic because my $geoNear stage has results limit and in this case items that are far away from input point won't appear even if they match the $match stage.

If I do a $match as first stage then I have a distance sort problem. The $geoNear is not an option since it has to be in first stage by definition. I can calculate the distance by myself and sort the results but this won't work since I do paging.

- **Note:** my aggregation performs search in a different table and than performs additional lookups before I get results that need to be sorted

It seems to me like a chicken and an egg problem.

Comment: `$geoNear` itself has [`query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#specify-which-geospatial-index-to-use) option to filter the documents.

Comment: actually that is not an option since my aggregations performs search in a different table and than performs additional lookups before I get results that need to be sorted

Comment: You must show some code to explain what you are trying to do. It is quite difficult tell what is wrong without knowing the actual problem. Please edit your question with detailed explanation.